# How to add custom tab on product detail page in admin side (Opencart)

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am having a store in opencart.

Simply i need to put on custom field in the product detail section see the screenshot you will get the idea.

[image]

It should behave like other tabs.

I do not wish to change the product_form.tpl core file directly as i am developing the opencart extension.

Comment: Did you add the first tabs? add another one like that

Comment: i have not added any tab.

Comment: If you did not add them, see the source code

Answer (score 1):

To add new tab in product edit form using OCmod -

1. Create new file and copy below code in it. Save this file with extension .ocmod.xml (example - addtab.ocmod.xml)

   ```
   <modification>
   <name>Add tab</name>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <link>test</link>
   <author>test</author>
   <code>add_tab_to_product</code>

   <file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
   <operation>
   <search><![CDATA[<li><a href="#tab-design" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a></li>]]></search>
   <add position="after"><![CDATA[<li><a href="#tab-shipping" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_shipping; ?></a></li>]]></add>
   </operation>
   <operation>
   <search><![CDATA[<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-design">]]></search>
   <add position="before"><![CDATA[<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-shipping">Write contents of tab Shipping here...</div>]]></add>
   </operation>
   </file> 

   <file path="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
   <operation>
   <search><![CDATA[$data['tab_design'] = $this->language->get('tab_design');]]></search>
   <add position="after"><![CDATA[$data['tab_shipping'] = $this->language->get('tab_shipping');]]></add>
   </operation>
   </file>

   </modification>
   ```
2. Go to Extension > extension installer, click on the upload button and upload above saved file.
3. Check that the extension is present and enabled in the modification list. Refresh cache ( Extension > Modification > Refresh cache ).

Refresh your page and you will get to see **Shipping** tab in product edit form.

This is tested with OpenCart version 2.1.x

Answer (score 0):

Aki,

If you are using opencart2.x then You will using ocmod to make custom tab on the product_form.tpl as well controller and model file. You don't want to change core files for the opencart. so when you will update opencart then you files data will not lost.

OCMOD Ref.

1. https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System
2. http://ocextensions.co.uk/ocmod/ocmod

And if you are not using opencart2.x then you will use vqmod to create extension.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a little more then that as you forgot to add the tab_shipping to the "admin/language/en-gb/en-gb.php" file. The way that it is now it will work but will display "tab_shipping" on the tab instead of Shipping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification
            xmlns="https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vqmod/vqmod/master/vqmod.xsd">
            >
    <id>Add Shipping tab Product Page</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <vqmver>2.X</vqmver>
    <author>Your Name</author>
    <code>add_tab_to_product</code> 
    <file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<li><a href="#tab-design" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a></li>]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[<li><a href="#tab-shipping" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_shipping; ?></a></li>]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-design">]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-shipping">Write contents of tab Customize here...</div>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file> 

    <file path="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$data['tab_design'] = $this->language->get('tab_design');]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[$data['tab_shipping'] = $this->language->get('tab_shipping');]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file path="admin/language/en-gb/en-gb.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$_['tab_design']                    = 'Design';]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[$_['tab_shipping']                    = 'Shipping';]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```